# Is there a way to link existing mapped network drive to SharePoint Shared Documents or folder?

Tags: document-library, sync, mapped-folder, network-drive

I am attempting to establish a connection between an existing mapped network drive and my SharePoint site. My goal is to be able to make changes to any files within my mapped network drive and it will sync to the SharePoint document library and vice versa. The destination isn't strict for SharePoint, it can be a custom folder or the Shared Documents. The mapped network drive however is strict and needs to be our existing mapped network drive.

I understand this link below, but is a different solution where it creates a brand new mapped network drive to your SharePoint. I want to link an existing one.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2616712

Answer (score 1):

No that isn't possible. There are 2 ways you can achieve something similar though.

One is using search to create a content source to your network drive and then you can use SharePoint Search to find information.

The other is by creating a Site Page or a Web Part Page and add a Page Viewer web part to the page. this will allow you to connect the page viewer web part to the fully qualified UNC path of your file share and make it appear as if it is in SharePoint.

If you are looking to keep the files on the file share but get the advantages of using a SharePoint document library, that s just not possible.